# One "what is my ip" website shows a different ip than others

Tags: ip, nat

When I go to the website http://whatismyip.akamai.com/ It shows that my IP is 100.87.1.114. When I go to any other website (such as https://whatismyipaddress.com/ or https://www.whatismyip.com/) telling me my public IP address I get 84.236.1.251.

When I go to 192.168.1.1 (my router's configuration page) under status/network interface there is an entry named IP which is the same 100.87.1.114. There is also an entry which says NAT is enabled.

I don't know what NAT is, but from what I read I think this means that the 100.87.1.114 IP is a private IP between my router and my ISP. Is this correct? If so shouldn't all online websites list the same public IP (84.236.1.251), or is there something special about http://whatismyip.akamai.com? If this is not correct, than please explain what NAT means.

On a bit of a side note this whole thing came up because I was trying to port forward which I did on my router, however online port checkers still showed the port as closed (port 2222 on which I have an ssh server running on my computer), and I can't ping my IP from the outside (my mobile phone with WiFi turned off with mobile data, I tried both public IPs). I have read somewhere that this could be caused by my ISP enabling NAT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know what NAT is

It literally means "address translation". For example, when your computer has a private 192.168.x IP address and needs to connect to the Internet, your router quietly edits all packets to have the router's public IP address instead. That's the usual kind of NAT.

> I have read somewhere that this could be caused by my ISP enabling NAT.

Yes, your ISP has put you behind a second layer of NAT – your own router doesn't have its own public IP address anymore. It only gets an address from the 100.64.0.0/10 private-use range (which was actually reserved for ISP-level NAT).

Akamai is special because it's a CDN, and a significant part of how it works is dedicated connections to ISPs and occasionally even placing their equipment (cache servers) directly in the ISPs' network. This means that when e.g. customers start downloading [Fortnite updates](https://www.zdnet.com/article/last-weeks-fortnite-update-helped-akamai-set-a-new-cdn-traffic-record/), the ISP can deliver them via dedicated connection or even simply out of their local network, without affecting the ISP's main connection to the Internet at all.

(If you run `tracert whatismyip.akamai.com`, you will probably see a *very* short path. Other CDNs such as CloudFlare also work in a similar way, although not all of them actually provide cache equipment directly to ISPs.)

So what's happening is that the Akamai server you're hitting counts as "inside" the ISP's network and your connection to it simply doesn't reach the 2nd layer of NAT (CGNAT), so it sees the ISP-provided private IP address.

(I'm not sure if that's intentional or misconfiguration on the ISP's part. On the one hand, third-party CDN servers definitely seem like they should count as "outside" – but on the other hand it probably reduces load on the CGNAT hardware by a very significant amount.)